# Buying Brakes for custom kick scooter with 12" diameter bmx wheels

Tags: brakes, bike-fit

I need to buy brakes for a custom kick scooter. The steel tubing of the entire frame is 1" in diameter. How do I know what size brakes to buy?

Comment: Welcome to [bicycles.se] @tyra. I'm afraid I don't understand your question. What kind of brakes are you trying to fit? How will you mount them? How will you operate them? If you got the wheels from a BMX bike, can you take the brakes also? It's an interesting question, so please edit to add more detail so we can help!

Comment: I've only seen one scooter of approximately this description, and it had drum brakes.

Comment: I wouldn't bother - kids small enough to ride this kind of bike lack the hand strength to work a hand brake.   A back-pedal brake is more common for that age group, but your scooter won't have that option.  Consider another bike, a 16" might be the appropriate size once the kid has grown enough.

Comment: Hi tyra - this question is 6 months old, and has no answer.  Would you like to  post and accept your own new answer describing how it has gone for you in the past  6 months.  What did you do for your kick scooter ?